# Postfix 3.1 not supporting mysql type

Tags: email, mysql, postfix, ubuntu-16.04

New mail server hosted on Ubuntu 16.04, supposed to be (postfix, dovecot, mysql), i installed postfix and mysql as follows:

```
apt install postfix postfix-mysql mysql-server mysql-client
```

After configuring postfix (3.1), i tried to test postfix and mysql connection and retrieve all domains / users:

```
postmap -q mydomain.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
```

I got the error:

```
postmap: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
```

Seems my server doesn't support mysql for some reason!

```
# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
inline
internal
memcache
nis
pipemap
proxy
randmap
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unionmap
unix

/etc/postfix# cat dynamicmaps.cf 
# dict-type so-name (pathname)  dict-function   mkmap-function
cdb postfix-cdb.so.1.0.1    dict_cdb_open   mkmap_cdb_open
ldap    postfix-ldap.so.1.0.1   dict_ldap_open
mysql   postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1  dict_mysql_open
pcre    postfix-pcre.so.1.0.1   dict_pcre_open
pgsql   postfix-pgsql.so.1.0.1  dict_pgsql_open
sqlite  postfix-sqlite.so.1.0.1 dict_sqlite_open
```

Help please?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install postfix-mysql` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: still same issue `postmap: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql`, the extension already exists "postfix-mysql", but not included in postfix supported list!

Comment: Okay, look over this thread for some "potential" solutions creating symlink or connecting to `127.0.0.1:3306`, etc. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322615

Comment: I did created symlink `ln -s postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1 dict_mysql.so`, didn't work, also i tried to copy the dynamic file `cp /usr/share/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf /etc/postfix/`, didn't work either!

Comment: Keep digging and researching; I'll check in later to see if you've solved the mystery.